# Sample dag tries to save execution_date param as null

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have an issue after upgrade from airflow 2.0.1 to 2.1.0 . When I run sample dag and it fails I am unable to save a row in `task_fail` table.

`ERROR:  null value in column "execution_date" violates not-null constraint`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from test_methods import test_python_method, test_python_log

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(
    'Sample-Dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date= datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Task-1',
        python_callable=test_python_method,
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Task-2',
        python_callable=test_python_log,
    )

    task_1 >> task_2
```

I can add config if it will help, but it's probably because of the Dag structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you likely did not do `airflow db upgrade`.

You always have to run this after migration to a newer Airflow version.